# The definition of $\wedge$ using $\lor$ and $\neg$

Tags: logic

We have that $\neg(A\wedge B)\iff \neg A\lor\neg B.$ How can I get the definition of $\wedge$ using $\lor$ and $\neg?$

I am new to logic and don't know how to start. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: so $ (A\wedge B)\iff\neg( \neg A\lor\neg B)...$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, can you explain that to me? I don't see it. thank you in advance :)

Comment: simply negate both sides of $\iff$, and note that $\lnot\lnot(A\land B)\iff(A\land B)$

Comment: Thank you! But why $\neg(\neg A\lor\neg B)$ is $(A\wedge B)?$

Comment: $\lnot(C\lor D)\iff C\land D$, and $\lnot\lnot X\iff X$

Comment: I see it now. We have $A\wedge B \iff \neg(\neg A\lor\neg B),$ right? Can we simplify the right side?

Comment: By right side, I mean $\neg(\neg A\lor\neg B)$. :)

Comment: Was my question clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A \land B = \lnot(\lnot A \lor\lnot B)$

Comment: Thank you for the response! I am not really sure how you saw that. Can you explain it to me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: it' just a negation of both sides of $\lnot (A\land B) \Leftrightarrow \lnot A \lor \lnot B$

Comment: Thank you! But why $\neg(\neg A\lor\neg B)$ is $(A\wedge B)?$